# MySQL/PHP Array to Javascript

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

So I want to store all of my MySQL results in an array I can manipulate with javascript/jQuery.

Here is my current code:

```
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM potentials";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    $potential = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    echo json_encode($potential);
?>
```

And my Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var myArray = "<?php print(json_encode($potential)); ?>";
        console.log(myArray)
    )};
</script>
```

I keep getting "Unexpected number" or "unexpected identifier". Whats going on?

Comment: it echos out fine, but doesnt console.log in the javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`json_encode()` returns an object using JSON notation. Strangely, you surrounded it with quotes. Try removing them :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var myArray = <?php print(json_encode($potential)); ?>;
    console.log(myArray);
});
</script>
```

(and it's not an array, it's an object, so you might want to rename your variable ;) )

Comment: Its now spitting out only the first row of potentials. How to I get all rows? a multidemensional array? what would that look like? maybe a foreach statement?

Comment: I would go for something like this :

    <?php
    $sql  = "SELECT * FROM potentials";
    $result  = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    $potential = array();

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
     $potential[] = $row;
    }

    echo '<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var myArray = "' . json_encode($potential) . '";
            console.log(myArray)
        )};
    </script>' . "\n";
    ?>

Comment: Note: replace )}; with }); at line 5 of the answer to prevent 'unexpected token )' bug in console.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `json_encode()` twice, however if you want to use it, you need to parse it. In jQuery this can be done via `jQuery.parseJSON` like this

```
var myArray = jQuery.parseJSON('<?php print json_encode($potential); ?>');
```

Also if you want all the results, you need to loop the query (e.g. with `while`) and then save it to an array

```
$array = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array( mysql_query( $query ) )
{
    $array[] = $row;
}
```

Comment: That gives me this in the console: Uncaught TypeError: Object function (E,F){return new o.fn.init(E,F)} has no method 'parseJSON'

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    var data = '<?php echo $data; ?>';
    var json = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(json[0]); //etc
</script>
```

Notice that var data = ... is SINGLE QUOTED, so you catch the echo from php as a String